# A lots of ACK packet send by server

Tags: sockets, tcp

I use the opentelemetry-collector as a agent co-located with my Swoole(php) application.
AFAIK, tcp connections do not ACK each other ， I don't understand how this process happens, please help me .

```bash
10:40:33.774730 eth0  In  IP longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318 > new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750: Flags [.], ack 1595395123, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4109427885 ecr 4015762947], length 0
10:40:33.774737 eth0  Out IP new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750 > longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4015778307 ecr 4071644582], length 0
^[10:40:49.135056 eth0  In  IP longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318 > new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750: Flags [.], ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4109443246 ecr 4015778307], length 0
10:40:49.135058 eth0  Out IP new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750 > longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4015793667 ecr 4071644582], length 0
10:41:04.476416 eth0  In  IP longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318 > new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750: Flags [.], ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4109458606 ecr 4015793667], length 0
10:41:04.476423 eth0  Out IP new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750 > longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4015809027 ecr 4071644582], length 0
10:41:19.837258 eth0  In  IP longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318 > new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750: Flags [.], ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4109473967 ecr 4015809027], length 0
10:41:19.837261 eth0  Out IP new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750 > longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4015824388 ecr 4071644582], length 0
10:41:35.174230 eth0  In  IP longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318 > new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750: Flags [.], ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4109489325 ecr 4015824388], length 0
10:41:35.174236 eth0  Out IP new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750 > longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4015839747 ecr 4071644582], length 0
10:41:50.534243 eth0  In  IP longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318 > new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750: Flags [.], ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4109504685 ecr 4015839747], length 0
10:41:50.534245 eth0  Out IP new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750 > longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4015855107 ecr 4071644582], length 0
10:42:05.872673 eth0  In  IP longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318 > new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750: Flags [.], ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4109520045 ecr 4015855107], length 0
10:42:05.872676 eth0  Out IP new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750 > longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4015870467 ecr 4071644582], length 0
10:42:21.232720 eth0  In  IP longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318 > new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750: Flags [.], ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4109535405 ecr 4015870467], length 0
10:42:21.232723 eth0  Out IP new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750 > longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4015885827 ecr 4071644582], length 0
10:42:36.571147 eth0  In  IP longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318 > new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750: Flags [.], ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4109550766 ecr 4015885827], length 0
10:42:36.571152 eth0  Out IP new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750 > longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4015901187 ecr 4071644582], length 0
10:42:51.931373 eth0  In  IP longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318 > new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750: Flags [.], ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4109566126 ecr 4015901187], length 0
10:42:51.931375 eth0  Out IP new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750 > longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4015916547 ecr 4071644582], length 0
10:43:07.275810 eth0  In  IP longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318 > new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750: Flags [.], ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 4109581485 ecr 4015916547], length 0
10:43:07.275816 eth0  Out IP new-yisdk-service-cli-66c9cb9b78-dp2dk.33750 > longmao-opentelemetry-collector.default.svc.cluster.local.4318: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 4015931907 ecr 4071644582], length 0
```

I would like to know under what circumstances this would happen? It appears to send ack packets every 15 seconds ？

Comment: Read about _keepalive_, if this is indeed TCP.

Comment: Somebody has set TCP keepalive to a crazy value at both ends.